# Как подключится к серверу с предоставлением клиентского сертификата?

Tags: java, android

Есть сервер(`testLink` вида: www.example.com:88/api/ping), к которому нужно подключиться через протокол `SSL`. Так же в наличии есть два ключа `client.crt`(открытый) и `client_unpass.key`(приватный), то есть как я понимаю используется асимметричное шифрование. Сертификат самоподписанный. Через `curl` успешно подключаюсь к серверу с помощью команды

```bash
curl -k --key client_unpass.key --cert client.crt --url "testLink"
```

Как мне подключиться к нему через `Android` приложение желательно через `OkHttp` 3-й версии? Пробовал различные варианты которые находил и получал различные ошибки, например:

> SSLHandshakeException

Которые не смог решить.

Дополнительная информация о сервере, полученная с сайта https://www.digicert.com/help/:

> SSL certificate
>
> Key Length = 1024 
>   Signature algorithm = SHA256 + RSA (excellent) 
>   Secure Renegotiation: Supported
>
> SSL Certificate has not been revoked 
>   The certificate expires May 29, 2047 (10939 days from today) 
>   Certificate does not match name
>   SSL Certificate is not trusted

Например ошибку указанную выше, выдает пример с [habr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/194530/), вот как он уменя выглядит:

```java
private void test1() throws Exception {
    String password = "XXXXXX";

    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

    keystore.load(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pfx), password.toCharArray());

    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new AdditionalKeyStoresSSLSocketFactory(keystore);

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "UTF-8");
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

    final SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 88));

    ThreadSafeClientConnManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(manager, params);

    HttpGet httpPostRequest = new HttpGet(testLink);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    Log.e("test", "result = " + result);
}
```

Comment: добавьте код в вопрос

Comment: @MikhailVaysman кода много перепробовал, добавить один из вариантов?

Comment: Тот вариант который выдаёт описанную ошибку

Comment: @MikhailVaysman добавил, эту ошибку много примеров выдавало

Comment: Вроде бы здесь подробно написано: http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/https-with-client-certificates-on/

Comment: @sanmai javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: Нужно задать Trust anchor, т.е. ваш сам сертификат в его роли если у вас самоподписной

Comment: @sanmai а как его нужно задавать? Сертификат как в примере я указывал

Answer (score 0):

`CertificatePinner` тут не нужен. Ключ `-k` у `curl` означает не проверять сертификат.

В коде это будет выглядеть вот так

```
final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
    new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }
    }
};

final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0])
    .hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true).build();

String hostname = "site.com";
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://" + hostname)
    .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
System.out.println("finish, response = " + response.body().string());
```

Comment: 400 No required SSL certificate was sent. Как я понимаю минимум нужно подписывать данные открытым ключом.

Comment: Точнее сообщения приходят в зашифрованном виде, значит закрытый ключ необходимо в любом случае использовать для расшифровки. И так же при отправлении, нужно шифровать открытым, что бы сервер после расшифровал закрытым.

Comment: у сайта сертификат подписан известным регистратором или это самоподписанный сертификат?

Comment: самоподписанный.